# CKeditor link not saved as it should be

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ckeditor

I'm using CKeditor on a website. When I'm trying to save some link in text I wrote to DB. It gets saved differently. For example :

```
<a href=\"http://example.com/images/somefolder/en.pdf\">
```

is saved like that, even if I entered it like

```
<a href="http://example.com/images/somefolder/en.pdf">
```

I'm not using any plugin or something like that. Haven't even changed anything, just downloaded it and that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'we fixed it. Nedded to use stripshlashes() function in PHP. It was saved diferently in my DB.